# How to create multiple select boxes with dynamic data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm going to create a simple E-commerce application. I have API call, which returns variations object like below. I want to dynamically generate variation boxes in this example my aim is to generate 2 select boxes, the first which holds all Color options and the second which holds all Value options. Right now I am receiving one option value, I want to receive options value like the [image]image which I have referred to. In addition, the select boxes are dynamic there can be more than three variations. How can I achieve this result? Thanks in advance.

```js
var variations = [{
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core Black"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["11"] },
        ]
    },
    {
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core Green"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["13"] },
        ]
    },
    {
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core White"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["15"] },
        ]
    },
]


document.getElementById("generateVariations").addEventListener("click", () => {
    var html;
    variations.map(el => {
        html = el.NameValueList.map(nameValue => {
            return `<select name="${nameValue.Name}">
                     <option value="${nameValue.Value[0]}">${nameValue.Value[0]}</option>
                  </select>`
        })
    })

    document.getElementById("variations2").innerHTML = html.join('')

})
```

```html
<div id="variations2"></div>
<button id="generateVariations">Generate variations</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think is what you want.

```js
var variations = [{
    NameValueList: [{
        Name: "Color",
        Value: ["Cloud White / Core Black"]
      },
      {
        Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
        Value: ["11"]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    NameValueList: [{
        Name: "Color",
        Value: ["Cloud White / Core Green"]
      },
      {
        Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
        Value: ["13"]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    NameValueList: [{
        Name: "Color",
        Value: ["Cloud White / Core White"]
      },
      {
        Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
        Value: ["15"]
      },
    ]
  },
]

let colors = variations.map(v => v.NameValueList[0]);
let sizes = variations.map(v => v.NameValueList[1])

document.getElementById("generateVariations").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var colors_select = `<select name="${colors[0].Name}">
${colors.map(e=>{
return `<option value="${e.Value[0]}">${e.Value[0]}</option>`
}).join()}
                  </select>`
  var sizes_select = `<select name="${sizes[0].Name}">
${sizes.map(e=>{
return `<option value="${e.Value[0]}">${e.Value[0]}</option>`
}).join()}
                  </select>`

  document.getElementById("variations2").innerHTML = colors_select + sizes_select;

})
```

```html
<div id="variations2"></div>
<button id="generateVariations">Generate variations</button>
```